# Configure Open VPN on a local Centos 7 serer

Tags: centos, centos7, vpn, openvpn, openvpn-connect

I applied the configuration listed in this Website  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7

I was able to run the VPN server and it stay running, but not able to connect from the client after trying to connect as shown in the picture below
[image]

Logs after checking the server status:

```
openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-25 21:32:46 CST; 13min ago
 Main PID: 18741 (openvpn)
   Status: "Initialization Sequence Completed"
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-openvpn.slice/openvpn@server.service
           └─18741 /usr/sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config server.conf

May 25 21:32:46 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:32:46 2023 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
May 25 21:32:46 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:32:46 2023 Initialization Sequence Completed
May 25 21:32:48 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:32:48 2023 192.168.0.148:62830 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.0.148:62830, sid=7bccaacb 8595effe
May 25 21:32:49 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:32:49 2023 192.168.0.148:62831 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.0.148:62831, sid=1c641459 f17d5fad
May 25 21:33:48 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:48 2023 192.168.0.148:62830 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May 25 21:33:48 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:48 2023 192.168.0.148:62830 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May 25 21:33:48 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:48 2023 192.168.0.148:62830 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
May 25 21:33:49 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:49 2023 192.168.0.148:62831 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May 25 21:33:49 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:49 2023 192.168.0.148:62831 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May 25 21:33:49 localhost.localdomain openvpn[18741]: Thu May 25 21:33:49 2023 192.168.0.148:62831 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The client configuration are:

```
tls-client
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
proto udp
remote SERVER_IP_ADDRESS 1194 udp
dev tun
topology subnet
pull
user nobody
group nobody
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the client configuration to the following and was able to connect

```
client
proto udp
remote SERVER_IP_ADDRESS 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
verb 3
redirect-gateway def1
```

**Configuration details:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fMisf1bCRzyIDX4Dtisb7DT173rJBzDQBshafsR2QWo/edit?usp=sharing